# Can i miss the 2nd leg of the journey?

Tags: air-travel, usa

I need to fly from Lexington, KY to Houston, TX. Almost all airline fares are more than $500. But the interesting part is if I choose Dallas, TX as my final destination (layover/change plane in Houston, TX 1hr 15min), it costs less than $300.

So in this context, can I buy Lexington-Dallas flight and get off at Houston and not worry about Houston Dallas flight? What are the consequences?

Comment: It's called Hidden City ticketing. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airline_booking_ploys

Comment: Consider flying out of SDF (Louisville) and you may find lower fares.